# Mystery ghost MySQL insert query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My MySQL db has inserted rows which should not be there,  in a particular there is data in a column not generally used. I thought this would make it easy to find which PHP script was inserting the rows but i have searchd all insert querys for the entire site and cannot find which php script is running the insert query.

Its also very hard to replicate as this particular table has many crons updating it.

Can anyone please try point me in the right direction of how I might go about debugging this. Is there a stack track I can use to determine the originating php script. Because it hard to replicate and I've spend two days searching for the code causing the inserts Im open to suggestions.

Im normally quite good at debugging but this bug is like a ghost.

Comment: Just look over your code and find which scripts are capable of inserting data to that column.

Comment: yea did that, only 4 INSERT querys in entire code base none of which touch the column mentioned...very odd

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of, if you have looked at all your code including in all your old cron scripts, is to put an insert trigger on that table, and use it to find out what time of day your extra rows get inserted.

Nasty problem!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a horrible idea depending on your error reporting settings and what type of environment you are debugging in,  but if you are in a position to have some errors thrown I'd remove write permissions for the column in question and wait to see what script throws the error. If you are lucky log/report for the error will be written to include a script name and line.

Comment: Thanks Ethan, I think I'll give your suggestion a try.I'll let you know how I get on!

Comment: Hey Aaron,  just out of curiosity how did things resolve?  I have a feeling I might find myself in similar shoes one day.

Comment: Hi Ethan, yes your suggestion did indeed help. The reason th e bug was so hard to find was the two crons were interacting the first was inserting correctly rows but the second cron updated the wrong rows with incorrect data. It was a tricky bug for sure.

Comment: Glad to hear,  I'll file that for future reference.  If this or any other answer solved your problem be sure to accept it as the solution - that way future googlers will know what answer worked.